# SQL plus | column adjust in spool file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am spooling in .csv file from SQL plus a file with some data.

The settings of my sql plus are:

```
sqlplus -s xxxx/xxxx@xxx <<-eod >> $logdir/xxxx.log
set feedback off
    set pages 5000
    set trims on
    set linesize  500
    set term off heading on

    column SP                                       format a10
    column commercial_code      format a50
    column rateplan             format a50
    column priceplanoffer       format a50
    column payment_type         format a50
    column traffictype          format a50
    column direction            format a50
    column onnet_offnet         format a50
    column clasification        format a50
    column cdr_count            format 9999999999
    column event_count          format 9999999999
    column volume               format 9999999999
    column rated_volume         format 9999999999
    column duration             format 9999999999
    column rated_duration       format 9999999999
    column charged_amount       format 9999999999
```

The output is something like this (not 100% correct) :
https://ibb.co/furf1G

Sorry for the link, imgur does not allow me to post it as a picture here.

In any case, what is the desired one is to put the column CHARGED_AMOUNT **next** to column RATED_DURATION and not under SP.

I think this is must be something with sqlplus parameters, can you please help me?
How could I achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your select statement then you should put `CHARGED_AMOUNT next to column RATED_DURATION`.

Comment: from the output it looks like you linsize is too small, try to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

I edited set linesize  500 to 900 and restarted the process. The desired output was ok as checked.